# Show the estimate $x^n\leq Ce^{ax^2}$ for all $x\geq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, inequality

I'd like to show that
$$
\forall a>0\forall n\geq 0\exists C>0:\forall x\geq 0, x^n\leq Ce^{ax^2}.
$$
Let $a>0$ and $n\geq 0$ be given. Define $f(x)=x^ne^{-ax^2}$. It's clear that $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$. If I use the definition of limits, I would not get the conclusion, because you pick any $\epsilon>0$, say $\epsilon=1$, so that $f(x)<1$ holds for sufficiently large $x$. What do I do next? The value $C$ depends on the coice of $a,n$.

Comment: That is what the statement says: for any $a$ and $n$, there is a $C$ such that...

Comment: C has to depend on both a and n , and like Gary pointed that this is what you are supposed to prove

Comment: What do you want to do? Prove that $f(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$ or prove the inequalty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that for $x = 0$ the inequalty trivially holds for any $C>0$. Now consider $0<x<1$. In this case we have that $\exp(ax^2)>1$ and $1>x^n$ so the inequalty holds again (just take $C=1$). It remains to consider the case $x\geq 1$. The Taylor series of $\exp$ is given by $$\exp(ax^2) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(ax^2)^k}{k!}$$
and thus $$\exp(ax^2) > \frac{(ax^2)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}.$$ Since $x\geq 1$ it follows that $$\frac{\exp(ax^2)}{x^n}>\frac{a^{n+1}x^{n+2}}{(n+1)!}$$ or
$$\frac{(n+1)!}{a^{n+1}}\exp(ax^2) > x^{2n+2} > x^n$$
as $x^n$ is monotone in $n$ and $2n+2>n$.

Comment: That's pretty much what I've been looking for. Tough, I've a question: how did you deduce from the Taylor series to conclude that $\exp(ax^2) > \frac{(ax^2)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$?

Comment: $\exp(ax^2) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(ax^2)^k}{k!} = \frac{(ax^2)^0}{0!} + \frac{(ax^2)^1}{1!} + \cdots + \frac{(ax^2)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} + \cdots$ but since every term is nonnegative ($a> 0$), a single term is smaller than $\exp(ax^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = x^n/\exp(a x^2)$ with $a,n>0$, $x\geq 0$, and $n\in\mathbb Z$.  $f$ is continuous, $f(x)>0$, and  $f(0) = 0$.  So $f$ is bounded if $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)$ exists.

Let $g(x) = x^n/\exp(a x)$.  For $x>1$, $f(x)<g(x)$, but applying l'Hospital $n-1$ times yields $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} g(x)=0$, thus $f$ is bounded.